# Alternatives to AForge.NET

Tags: c#, machine-learning, aforge, ml.net

I'm wondering if there are any good alternatives to AForge.NET. I want to use ML.NET in my project, but then this warnings occur.

[image]

Comment: You get this warning because that library is compiled for .NET Framework 4.6.1-4.8. Since your project does target .NET 6, it gives this warning. You can use Accord. It's avaliable on NuGet.

Comment: but this is also very old

Comment: I assume that you want to do image processing mainly. What about using TensorFlow.NET?

Comment: Both Aforge & Accord are old. There are newer libraries like ML.Net, but if you want recommendations -> https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/